# Initialize spring bean profile through ContextLoaderListener in web.xml

Tags: java, spring, web.xml, servlet-listeners, spring-bean

In my `web.xml` I'm declaring a `ContextLoaderListener` to configure spring application this way:

```
<listener>    
   <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>    
</listener>
```

In one of my spring configuration xml files, I'm using different [beans profile](http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/) for development and production.

```
<beans profile="production">
   <bean />
</beans
<beans profile="development">
   <bean />
</beans
```

How I could set the default beans profile in the `web.xml`? is there something similar to the following when using `ContextLoaderListener` instead of spring servlet:

```
<init-param>
   <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
   <param-value>production</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can configure `web.xml` at the level of `ContextLoaderListener` with:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>profileName</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and the level of `DispatcherServlet` with:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>profileName</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Reference: http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/